# I am developing an application with React Native in Android Studio and I am using tailwindcss the project works but the tailwindcss output does not wo

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnDlP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjR04.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI38w.png)

I am using tailwindcss for the first time and especially in a react-native app. I followed the documentation, read some articles and watched some videos. I have my react-app running but tailwindcss classes do not reflect on the application. I have restarted the project from scratch severally but I still face the same issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text.  How did you include your tailwindcss classes in your react-app?

Comment: You may need to add details regarding the version of each technology and package you are using, maybe the most important peaces of code about those files that imply the use and declaration of tailwindcss so we can trace your code deeply

Comment: Hello, I added the images of Package-lock.json and package.json files.